# SQL Server 2008 and constant expressions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have the following scenario, would Replace be evaluated a single time?

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(32) = 'This is a test field'

SELECT textField FROM Table
WHERE Id = @idICareAbout AND textField = REPLACE(@text, ' ', '')
```

I would hope that it would, but I tend to be nervous about it and do this instead:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(32)
Select @text = REPLACE('This is a test field', ' ', '')

SELECT textField FROM Table
WHERE Id = @idICareAbout AND textField = @text
```

Of course replace here is just an example, and I'm sure this second variant is probably clearer and safer, but occasionally when I'm over optimizing, I think "What if I didn't have to do the replace at all, because the first part of the WHERE expression evaluates to false". Normally this would be such a micro-optimization it's silly to even think about but there have been a few times where the scenario is such that it may make a not miniscule difference. (Many more where clause parameters and maybe a bunch of HASHBYTES of parameters passed in.)

So I'm just curious how SQL server handles it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server optimizer does [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), when possible. But is not a black-or-white issue, there are many shades of gray. See [Compute Scalars, Expressions and Execution Plan Performance](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html) or [Troubleshooting Poor Query Performance: Constant Folding and Expression Evaluation During Cardinality Estimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175933%28v=sql.105%29). You also need to read [Conor vs. Runtime Constant Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions) to get a grasp what is 'constant' in SQL to start with.

See http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/ for an example when SQL Server does not do boolean short-circuit.